# What is needed in order to receive e-mail on a subdomain?

Tags: email, exim

I have an Exim mail server which takes care of mail for *domain.com*.

I have a MX record `mail.domain.com` which points to `mailserver.domain.com`, which is an `A record` to the server's IP.

If I want to receive mail for *sub.domain.com*, I have to add a MX record `mail.sub.domain.com` pointing to `mailserver.domain.com`. Is there anything else I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

Subdomains of registrable domain names are no more special than the
"raw" domain which has fewer components. To be able to receive e-mail
for domain *foo.example*, you would need:

- A DNS MX record of *foo.example* to *mx-foo.example*;
- A DNS A record of *mx-foo.example* to the address of a mail server;
- configuring the mail server so that it accepts mail for *foo.example* as local.

I believe you have all the right steps in your question, except for
the last one: making sure the mail server knows it is supposed to
handle mail for the extra domain *foo.example*.

Comment: A fixed IP address is also a requirement or at least a strong condition for reduced hassle with spam-aware senders and delivery delays. Implied with the question but I think worth mentioning.